# proper way to get schemaLocation to determine which xsd to load and which type to return?

Tags: c#, xml, reflection, xsd, versioning

I'm learning how to do "proper" unknown (but known) xml validation that use versioning

I got it working BUT i don't like how I'm doing it, my question is; I'm on the correct path here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace BLL.XML
{
    public class ValidateXML
    {
        //list of valid xsd files and the corresponding class
        private static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SchemaType;

        static ValidateXML()
        {
            SchemaType = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
            SchemaType.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sample.0.6.2.xsd", "BO.contentExchangeType, BO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"));
            SchemaType.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("sample.0.6.1.xsd", "BO.contentExchangeType11231321312, BO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"));
        }

        //valid xml
        private bool valid;
        //list of errors found while validating
        private List<string> errors;
        //list of warnings found while validating
        private List<string> warnings;

        private ValidateXML()
        {
            errors = new List<string>();
            warnings = new List<string>();

            valid = true; //by default, the xml is valid
        }

        public static KeyValuePair<bool, List<string>> Validate(string xml, out Type XmlType)
        {
            var validate = new ValidateXML();
            string xsd = "";

            try
            {
                using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
                using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(sr))
                {
                    if (xmlReader.MoveToContent() == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        //should look like this
                        //xsi:schemaLocation="http://sample.com/sample/contentExchange sample.0.6.2.xsd "
                        var schemaLocation = xmlReader.GetAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation");
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(schemaLocation))
                        {
                            var part = schemaLocation.Split();
                            if (part.GetUpperBound(0) >= 1)
                            {
                                //get the actual xsd file name for validation
                                xsd = part[1];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //xsd found in the predefined list?
                if (SchemaType.Any(x => x.Key == xsd))
                {
                    var xsdFile = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/xsd/" + xsd);
                    if(File.Exists(xsdFile))
                    {
                        //prepare the return type
                        XmlType = Type.GetType(SchemaType.First(x => x.Key == xsd).Value);

                        //validate the xml based on the proper xsd
                        return validate.VerifyXmlFile(xml, xsdFile);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Cannot find the file " + xsd );
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Cannot find matching xsd value");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                validate.errors.Add("Exception.Message: " + ex.Message);
                XmlType = null;
                return new KeyValuePair<bool, List<string>>(false, validate.errors);
            }

        }

        private KeyValuePair<bool, List<string>> VerifyXmlFile(string xml, string PathXsd)
        {
            try
            {
                using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(xml))
                using (XmlReader xsd = XmlReader.Create(PathXsd))
                {
                    // configure the xmlreader validation to use inline schema.
                    XmlReaderSettings config = new XmlReaderSettings();
                    config.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                    config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
                    config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
                    config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
                    config.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints;
                    config.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
                    config.Schemas.Add(null, xsd);

                    // Get the XmlReader object with the configured settings.
                    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr, config))
                    {
                        // Parsing the file will cause the validation to occur.
                        while (reader.Read()) ;

                        return new KeyValuePair<bool, List<string>>(valid, errors);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                errors.Add("Exception.Message: " + ex.Message);
                return new KeyValuePair<bool, List<string>>(false, errors);
            }
        }

        private void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs vea)
        {
            if (vea.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
            {
                valid = false;
                errors.Add("ValidationCallBack: " + vea.Message);
            }
            else if (vea.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
            {
                warnings.Add("ValidationCallBack: " + vea.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to be used like

```
var ValidXml = BLL.XML.ValidateXML.Validate(text, out XmlType);

if (ValidXml.Key)
{
    if (XmlType == typeof(contentExchangeType))
    {
        ProcessContentExchangeType062(text);
    }
    else if (XmlType == typeof(contentExchangeType11231321312))
    { 
        ProcessContentExchangeType061(text);             
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to add to you validation handler, to add in the custom XML attributes checks. So you just load the file, and then call validate. It would mean tweaking the code. Less if statements on checking if the file is of type XML etc.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162371.aspx

Comment: @Arnej65, code updated :-)